# R data.table keys and column names. Harmonisation

Tags: r, merge, data.table, key, tidyverse

I am trying to set keys yo a data.table and keep the original column names on the second row. All that I have tried so far changes the column names to keys and erases the original variables. I have ten data.tables to merge and all the variables have different names like in the example. So I made keys but would like to keep the originals as well before harmonisation just to be sure.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(forcats)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(rio)
library(dplyr)
```

## 1. Keys

```
keys1 <- c("SDC_GENDER","SDC_CHILD_NB","LAB_CRP","PM_HIP")
keys2 <- c("SDC_GENDER","SDC_CHILD_NB","LAB_CRP","PM_HIP")
```

## 2. data.table example with variable names.

```
TD3 = data.table(q128 = c(1, 2, 1, 2), q129 = c(1, 5, 2, 4), q130 = c(0.8, 3.0, 10.0, NA), q131 = c(55, 56, 80, 79))
TD3
TD4 = data.table(q128 = c(1, 1, 1, 2), q129 = c(1, 3, 2, 999), q130 = c(0.9, 3.1, NA, 9.0), q131 = c(58, 60, 45, NA))
TD4
```

Comment: Do all the data.frames have the exact same structure, i.e. number of columns?

Comment: Keeping the column names on the second row makes no sense to me. You can't have `character` on one row and `numeric` on another, as you have here. What you are talking about is not compatible with the definition of dataframe in most languages. You can save the old names elsewhere (not in each frame) before renaming.

Comment: Yes, same number of columns at this stage.  I made key for each variable name for each column in each data.table.

Comment: The original column names are just like q128, q129, q130 and so on. But just different in every R data.table. I try to harmonise tables with keys which are like SDC_GENDER and so on. But at this point would like to keep both the keys and original variable names in the data.tables. Now I have the same tables with original variable column names and with the keys.

Comment: Now I noticed that, while being to tired, made the same variable names (q128...) for both data.tables. Supposed to be different, so they don't mach. I'll make a new example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really the data structure you want to have, that is to have mixed variable types like r2evans said. However...this solution works. Just put all your little data.tables into a list and voila.

I noticed that keys1 and keys2 are identical, so I just used one of them. If they should be different keys for each they can also be listed.

```
keys1 <- c("SDC_GENDER","SDC_CHILD_NB","LAB_CRP","PM_HIP")
TD <- list()
TD[[1]] = data.table(q128 = c(1, 2, 1, 2), q129 = c(1, 5, 2, 4), q130 = c(0.8, 3.0, 10.0, NA), q131 = c(55, 56, 80, 79))
TD[[2]] = data.table(q128 = c(1, 1, 1, 2), q129 = c(1, 3, 2, 999), q130 = c(0.9, 3.1, NA, 9.0), q131 = c(58, 60, 45, NA))
TD <- lapply(TD, FUN = function(x){
  oldcolumns <- colnames(x)

    td <- data.table(
    'V1' = oldcolumns[1],
    'V2' = oldcolumns[2],
    'V3' = oldcolumns[3],
    'V4' = oldcolumns[4]
  )
    colnames(td) <- keys1
  colnames(x) <- keys1

  x <- rbind(td, x)
  return(x)

})
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this! It is just makes harmonisation of the tables more clear at this point if you can see both original labels and keys in the same tables.